# Re-order items when I hit a custom breakpoint

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have four items with different sizes in a row.
On extra-large screens everything looks fine. But when I hit large screens (1199.98px / bootstrap 'lg'), I need to re-order my div items.

The third div need to be the last.
I also made a code pen for this

```
<!-- https://codepen.io/ibrahim-kunushefci/pen/OKJWzq -->
```

```css
.hotelPr,
.hotelPr2,
.hotelPr3 {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background: #3161a3;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.custom {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background: #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hotelPr">
            <p>Hotel</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hotelPr2">
            <p>Hotel</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-10">
        <div class="custom">
            <p>This needs to be the last on small, medium and large screens. But not in extra large</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hotelPr3">
            <p>Hotel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order You can reorder columns as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `d-flex` to your `row` container:

Add `order-1 order-xl-0` to your the col you need to re-order

Comment: There's no need to add `d-flex`.. The row is `display:flex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the order of the displayed siblings on a parent flexbox element.

I changed the display of your `.row` div in a flexbox, and I added an `order` property to your `col-xl-5` div.

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
}

.hotelPr,
.hotelPr2,
.hotelPr3 {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background: #3161a3;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.custom {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background: #bbbbbb;
}

.col-xl-5{
  order: 1; /* here */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hotelPr">
            <p>Hotel</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hotelPr2">
            <p>Hotel</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-10">
        <div class="custom">
            <p>This needs to be the last on small, medium and large screens. But not in extra large</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hotelPr3">
            <p>Hotel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```